# "topological" Ochanine genus?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, stable-homotopy

The Witten genus has famously been lifted to the [string orientation of tmf](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%20orientation%20of%20tmf) ("topological Witten genus"). For the Ochanine genus, I am aware of a lift to a "[spin orientation of Tate K-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin%20orientation%20of%20Tate%20K-theory)", namely, to a map of ring spectra $M \mathrm{Spin}\to KO[ [q] ]$: lemma 5.4, 5.8 in

- Matthias Kreck, Stefan Stolz, *$HP^2$-bundles and elliptic homology*, Acta Math, 171 (1993) 231-261

At least naively, one would hope to see a further refinement of the Ochanine genus to an orientation of something like $tmf_0(2)$. Is there any reason for why this should not work? Or has it just not been considered?

Comment: Is there a difference between $tmf_0(2)$ and the elliptic cohomology theory constructed by Landweber, Ravenel, Stong? They construct a (homotopy commutative) orientation on their elliptic cohomology theory as I remember. Their theory has 2 inverted, but I suspect that a construction of $tmf_0(2)$ as an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum would also have 2 inverted. I should admit that I am a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: Mild clarification: Since the spectrum of LRS is periodic, I should be asking if Tmf_0(2)$ is the same as their spectrum. Note any orientation lifts to their connective covers canonically up to homotopy so we could rephrase the question in terms of the periodic forms.

Comment: I see, thanks, I was missing the obvious. Yes, you are right (e.g. top of p. 4 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507184).

Comment: I just stumbled across this question again. Dylan Wilson answered it in the affirmative: http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05116